What's the name of this "cat" horror film?
I am sorry for the lack of information, but I saw this film when I was very young (I was around 4).
It's most likely from the 80's or the very early 90's (when I saw it). It's an American film. I watched it on TV so it may have been a TV movie. 
The only part I remember:
The cat (from its point of view) backs up a few people into a corner (The camera races towards them). The room looked to be older fashioned (70's/80's). It was a man, a woman and two kids. The cat was black. Then it dissolves into the point of view of either the cat running in the middle of the road (day time) or the P.O.V. of a car. I believe the credits rolled during the POV in the road. The score during the scene sounded a bit like the beginning to the A Nightmare on Elm Street theme. 

Cat from Hell?

The Black Cat or Cat People ?

Pet Sematary? It features a black cat with a family of four.

I believe this to be the 1991 made for TV movie Strays.
The movie is about a family from the city moving out to an old house in the country. There is a big black demon type cat, who is referred to as a dominant male, living in the basement and he has shacked up with a bunch of female cats forming a sort of evil den of cats.
The movie utilizes the 'Evil Dead' style camera angle that you describe fairly often to signify an evil cat sneaking up and pouncing on someone.
In the end I think the family gets away, but it shows that the main cat has also survived and like most horror movies leaves it open for a sequel.

I edited my answer to add as many connective elements as I can remember. I feel confident that it is the right answer though.

Yeah, it is possible the OP got some of the details wrong. It does almost end with a cat's POV along a trail, and a black cat does back up a kid against a cabinet.

Thanks everyone for your answers and comments so far. "Strays" is a good guess but unfortunately its not the film.

Bummer, I really thought that was it...
